# Top-level expression evaluation at compile time

Tags: haskell, compile-time-constant

Is there any way to ensure, that an expression like the following would be evaluated at compile time?

```
myList :: [Int]
myList = sort [3,2,0,1]
```

Comment: You can check the generated Core to see if that optimization was performed. But, AFAIK, there is no way to force that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If what you're evaluating is an instance of [`Lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:Lift), you can evaluate it at compile time using [`TemplateHaskell`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_Haskell):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Sort where

import Data.List
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

myList :: [Int]
myList = $(lift (sort [3,2,0,1] :: [Int]))
```

If you want, you can check what it has compiled to with `-ddump-splices`:

```
$ ghc -ddump-splices sort
[1 of 1] Compiling Sort             ( sort.hs, sort.o )
sort.hs:9:12-41: Splicing expression
    lift (sort [3, 2, 0, 1] :: [Int]) ======> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```